# SSRS R2 Combining two reports with alternating worksheet result

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to combine two different reports (with totally different datasources) where in the result would be to create an alternating excel worksheets via R2 pagebreaks like "Daily SS", "MTD SS", "Daily RR", "MTD RR", "Daily LL", "MTD LL"...

First report contains the Daily data and the other report contains the MTD data.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a tablix report, you can put all the tables inside a single reports and add page breaks to each table by selecting "Add a page break after" under Page break options in tablix properties.

You can refer this link to get more understanding:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Abhilash,Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion but it didn't help me have an alternating tabs for Daily and MTD data. It iterated on MTD first before adding the Daily tabs.